# Field API isn't saving data

Tags: hooks, entities

I have looked through multiple tutorials and I don't know what I'm missing.

I have created a new field type using the Field API and it's displaying everything perfectly, but when I try to put information in the textfield and hit save, nothing shows up on the form after the submit and nothing gets put in the database.

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?  Here is an example of the code I've written:

in the module.install file i have:

```
function cptc_test_field_schema($field) {
 $columns = array(
 'field_test' => array(
   'type' => 'int',
   'unsigned' => TRUE,
   'not null' => FALSE,
 ),
);
return array('columns' => $columns);
}
```

and in the module.module file i put

```
function cptc_test_field_info(){
return array(
'field_test'=> array(
  'label' => 'test',
  'description' => 'test crap',
  'default_widget' => 'widget_test',
  'default_formatter' => 'formatter_test',
 ),
);
}


function cptc_test_field_widget_form(&$form, &$form_state, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $delta, $element) {  
$value = isset($items[$delta]['value']) ? $items[$delta]['value'] : '';
switch($instance['widget']['type']){
case 'widget_test':
  $element['widget_test'] = $element + array(
    '#title' => 'Additional Email Addresses',
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#default_value' => '',
    '#size' => 60,
  );
  break;
default:
break;
}
$element['#element_validate'][] = 'cptc_test_field_widget_validate';
return $element; 
}
```

There's a lot more to it (obviously), but figured that I shouldn't post everything - for expediency's sake. The other hooks I have implemented are:

```
hook_field_is_empty
hook_field_validate
hook_field_widget_error
hook_test_field_widget_info
hook_test_field_widget_validate
hook_test_field_formatter_info
hook_test_field_formatter_view
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your function `cptc_test_field_widget_form()`, change 
`$element['widget_test']` to `$element['field_test']`. and make sure your `hook_field_is_empty()` has the following line of code:

```
return empty($item['field_test']);
```

Answer (score 0):

My first thought looking at that is that your widget is defining a textfield, size 60, but your database is only made to hold an integer.

Comment: I've changed it to a varchar with a length of 255, but no change :\

Comment: Did you do an uninstall/install? Is the database field a varchar now?

Comment: Also, have you looked in the error log to see if the database is throwing up any errors?